# jQuery parse data array unexpected token

Tags: jquery, arrays, parsing, templates

I have a problem parsing data array with jQuery `parseJSON`, returns:

> SyntaxError:Unexpected token in JSON at position 1

```js
var selected = $('input[type=radio][name=packs]:checked');
gf_allowed = $.parseJSON(selected.data('gf_allowed'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="packs" value="361" data-price="22,00" data-desc=" 2 GGFF + BUGGIE(22.00EUR pax)" data-gf_exact="True" data-gf_allowed="[&quot;2&quot;, &quot;4&quot;]" checked="true">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to share the entire js code/file if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is because jQuery has already recognised the value held in the attribute is JSON and therefore parsed it to an object for you. Your call to parse it again is what's causing the problem.

To fix the issue just remove the `$.parseJSON()` call:

```js
var selected = $('input[type=radio][name=packs]:checked');
var gf_allowed = selected.data('gf_allowed'); // jQuery has already parsed this for you

console.log(gf_allowed);
console.log(gf_allowed[1]); // = 4
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="packs" value="361" data-price="22,00" data-desc=" 2 GGFF + BUGGIE(22.00EUR pax)" data-gf_exact="True" data-gf_allowed="[&quot;2&quot;,&quot;4&quot;]" checked="true">
```